# Замена пункта MenuStrip с MDI Сhild у MDI Parent

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте.

`MDI` приложение, в котором с помощью меню обрамляющей формы,совершаются некие действия с дочерними.
В `MenuStrip` обрамляющей формы добавлен пункт `&Window`, к нему добавлены два подпункта `&Set all color` `&Set color`.
На дочерней форме также добавлен пункт `&Window` и два этих же подпункта. Для пунктов `&Window` определен `MergeAction - Replace`.
В дочерней форме пункт `&Set Color` устанавливает цвет формы,а в пункте `&Set all color` вызывается обработчик одноименного пункта с обрамляющей формы.

Вопрос следующий: по заданию необходимо вывести в `&Window` список дочерних окон, из-за того, что `&Window` заменяется соответствующим пунктом из обрамляющей формы, получить список дочерних окон не получается (проблема именно в том, что список пропадает при замене). Как исправить, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Насколько понимаю,верно было бы не заменять один &Window на другой,а выполнить их слияние,но как - не знаю.

Comment: Мне кажется, что дело тут как раз в `MergeAction`. Сейчас там Megre, но могут быть и [другие значения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.mergeaction(v=vs.110).aspx), попробуйте поэксперементировать... И вот еще [статья с примерами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5523fet0(v=vs.110).aspx), надеюсь, окажется полезной.